# Convert From Local Time to UTC (Given the local TimeZone)

Tags: vb.net

I've dates in different time zones.

How to convert them to UTC giving the respective time zone.

Something like this:

```
Dim Dated as DateTime = TempDate.ConvertToUniversalTime(TimeZone)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it

```
Dim TimeZone As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time")
Dim Dated As DateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(TempDate, TimeZone)
```

For the TimeZones IDs check:

```
TimeZone.GetSystemTimeZones
```

Answer (score 4):

The [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) object in .net provides the [DateTime.ToUniversalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) method. Since you are using the VB [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e(VS.80).aspx) type the [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(VS.80).aspx) and [DateTime.ToOAdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(VS.80).aspx) will provide conversion between the Date and DateTime types (see *Interop Considerations* under *Programming Tips* [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e(VS.80).aspx)).

**UPDATE:** You might also want to check out [Converting Times Between Time Zones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx).

Comment: The DateTime.ToUniversalTime as I can tell uses the system TimeZone for the conversion. The Dates I need to convert are in different TimeZones.